# Sony VAIO VGN-SZ44GN + Windows 7, doesn't detect monitor

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, sony-vaio

Has anyone with this VAIO been able to install Windows 7 and have it detect the monitor and graphics adaptor?

Am just getting "Standard VGA" for the display, and "Generic Non-PnP" for the Monitor.

Resolution is limited to 1024 x 768 as a result.

Any ideas? I can't find any drivers that would work.

Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by exploding the driver from NVIDIA and then grabbing one of the inf files manually.

Answer (score 0):

1 : INDVID-01597901-UN

2 :  NVDVID-01360403-UN

This is video driver, this file found this link.....

http://www.sony-asia.com/support/download/product/vgn-sz44gn/modelfirst